# Making paragraph responsive in CSS

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and have encountered a problem. I'm trying to display paragraphs on my website on desktop/global view as

```
#aeromexico

p {
float: left;
position: fixed;
text-align: left;
max-width: 25%;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

but when viewed in mobile and tablet I want them to be viewed as

```
#aeromexico .col-sm
p {
    object-position: top;
    text-align: left;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

However the second part of the code for mobile view is being ignored and is still displaying as desktop view on mobile. I have attached my whole code below

/*Desktop / Global View*/

```
body  {
max-width: 1366px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
padding: 1px;


}

#homepage .col {
float: left;
}


.col-lg {
width: 33.3%;
}

.col-lg img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}

.slicknav_menu  {
display:none;
}


#menu {
float: right;
}

#menu li {
display:inline-block;
}

#menu li a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #454545;
padding: 8px;
font-size: 18px;

}

header {
padding: 10px 0px 20px 0px;


}

ul {
padding-top: 40px;
}

.mylogo {
width: 95px;
}





/*aeromexico*/ 

#aeromexico .row {
padding:5px;
}

#aeromexico .col {
width: 70%; 
margin-right: auto;
float: right;
display:inline-block;
padding-bottom: 40px;

}

#aeromexico .col-lg {
width: 65%;
}


#aeromexico

p {
float: left;
position: fixed;
text-align: left;
max-width: 25%;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
display:inline-block;
}


/*Tablet View*/


@media (max-width: 768px) {


#menu li {
    display:block;
    text-align: right;

}
header {
    padding:10px;
}

.col-md {
    width: 50%;
}

.mylogo {
width: 95px;
}

body {
        padding:10px;


}

}



/*Mobile View*/


@media (max-width: 400px)   {
.slicknav_menu  {
display:block;
}


#menu {
    display:none;
}

alt {
    width: 95px;
}

.mylogo {
width: 95px;
}

.col-sm {
    width:100%;
}
    body {
        padding:10px;
    }

    #aeromexico .col-sm {
        width:100%;
    }

    #aeromexico .col-sm
p {

    object-position: top;
        text-align: left;
        max-width:100%;
        display:block;
        padding-bottom: 60px;

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the metatag for the viewport on the HTML header?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```